# Restore transaction doesn't download the content IAP IOS

Tags: ios, storekit, in-app-purchase

I have been struggling with this issue since 2 days. I have implemented In App purchase successfully with downloadable content . But whenever I delete app and restore the purchase , restore doesn't actually download the content. But if I add download code in restoreTransaction it never calls finish transaction which cause the app to behave weirdly(which is resonable) , every time I delete app and reinstall it. Any help is appreciated!!
Please let me know if anyone needs further explanation. Thanks!!

```
    - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
  {
   for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

            if(transaction.downloads)
                [self download:transaction];
            else

               [self completeTransaction:transaction];

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

            if(transaction.downloads)
               [self restoreDownload:transaction];
            else
               [self restoreTransaction:transaction];

        default:
            break;
    }
};
}


 -(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads
{
 for (SKDownload *download in downloads)
  {
    switch (download.downloadState) {

        case SKDownloadStateActive:
            NSLog(@"Download progress = %f",
                  download.progress);
            NSLog(@"Download time = %f",
                  download.timeRemaining);
            break;
        case SKDownloadStateFinished:
        {

           NSLog(@"URL %@",download.contentURL);
          }

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}


 - (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
  NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

  [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];

  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
   }


   - (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
      NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");


   [self  provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
   }

 - (void)restoreDownload:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
 NSLog(@"restoreDownload...");

  //[self validateReceiptForTransaction:transaction];
   [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];

   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];

  }

 - (void)download:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
NSLog(@"Download Content...");

[self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
//[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

}
```

Comment: Finally i was able to find the solution for this problem with help of one nice guy over Stackoverflow chat room. The problem was that whenever paymentQueue callback calls restoreDownload , it never calls restoreTransaction in order to finish the transaction. So transaction was always in hanging state and never finished after downloading content. So whenever i delete app and reinstall it ,it will always go to paymentQueue callback and eventually to SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored to finish transaction , but will always encounter restoreDownload first.

Comment: So the point is to finish transaction after downloading which now I can do in SKDownloadStateFinished: by writing this piece of code :" [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:download.transaction];". so now it will always finishTransaction after download. Let me know if anybody has any question regarding this .Thanks

Comment: I am experiencing this issue. And even after your explanation, I do not understand why the content is not downloaded. So, lets assume we forgot to finish the transaction. We launch the app again, it detects a transaction with a "restored" state and then it encounters the `startDownloads` call. Why does it not start downloading content?